# Erase/Remove contents from the map (or any other STL container) while iterating it

Tags: c++, stl

Allegedly you cannot just erase/remove an element in a container while iterating as iterator becomes invalid. What are the (safe) ways to remove the elements that meet a certain condition? please only stl, no boost or tr1.

**EDIT**
Is there a more elegant way if I want to erase a number of elements that meet a certain criteria, perhaps with  using  functor and for_each or erase algorithm ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bool IsOdd( int i )
{
    return (i&1)!=0;
}

int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> v( a, a + 5 );
v.erase( remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), bind1st( equal_to<int>(), 4 ) ), v.end() );
// v contains {1,2,3,5}
v.erase( remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), IsOdd ), v.end() );
// v contains {2}
```

Comment: bind1st creates a function like object that essentially gives you a function call with a constant first parameter - so in the example it would have the effect of equal_to<int>(4, X) where X comes from the sequence that we are iterating over.  The effect is that each value in the sequence is compared with 4.

Answer (score 35):

You can as long as you don't invalidate your iterator after you've erased it:

```
MyContainer::iterator it = myContainer.begin();
while(it != myContainer.end())
{
    if (*it == matchingValue)
    {
       myContainer.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. "myContainer.erase(it++);" is subtle -- it correctly performs the increment *before* calling erase(), when it is still valid to do so, while passing (a copy of) the *unincremented* iterator to that function.

Comment: IMPORTANT: That code works for map, set and list, but it will NOT work for vector -- erasing from a vector invalidates iterators to that and all subsequent elements (23.2.4.3/3). Have dropped my +1 for now, will re+1 when you mention this.

Comment: Are you sure that the increment is before calling erase? AFAIK the increment is guaranteed to be done before the end of the sentence, but the correct order is implementation specific. For example a gnu in debug mode does something like this `v.erase(it), it++`, but in release mode does `tmp = it, ++it, v.erase(tmp)`.

Comment: @Ismael: Postincrement returns an unmodified *copy* of its operand before incrementing. The STL iterators guarantee this.

Comment: The post-increment takes place before calling erase(), because the value is required for the call. Erase() gets a copy of the unincremented pointer.

Comment: @Ismael: function calls are sequence points, so the side effects from the increment are guaranteed to be done before the call to erase begins.

Comment: Guys, it doesn't matter if the increments occurs before or after the value is passed to erase. For the sake of maintenance, save off the erase iterator, increment the loop iterator, then erase with the erase iterator, then comment why you have to do it in that order.

Comment: This solution seems needlessly obscure. Why would you not just do `it = myContainer.erase(it);`. It's much more obvious what's going on that way, and doesn't rely on the ordering of the increment.

Comment: @TimAngus Prior to C++11, std::map::erase(iterator) was a void function. This answer was written in 2009 prior to the publishing of C++11 in September 2011.

Comment: Ah, fair enough then.

Answer (score 12):

Example with std::vector

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   typedef vector <int> int_vector;

   int_vector v(10);

   // Fill as: 0,1,2,0,1,2 etc
   for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i){
      v[i] = i % 3;
   }

   // Remove every element where value == 1    
   for (int_vector::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); /* BLANK */){
      if (*it == 1){
         it = v.erase(it);
      } else {
         ++it;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Didnt know about that, but isnt the iterator returned from erase a new, validated one?

Sounds very strange that it would return an invalid iterator?

Comment: @j_random_hacker: you are correct that it invalidates any iterators..but std::vector::erase returns a *new*, *valid* iterator to the element after the erased one (or end). This code is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're absolutely right -- must have misread your code. The iterator returned by erase refers to the next element (23.1.1/7). +1.

Comment: Deleted my 1st comment so as not to confuse anyone who just reads it... But yes, FTR I wrongly accused Viktor of summoning undefined behaviour :-/

Comment: Good example, but in order to work for map (and its friends), you can not use the return value of erase() -- for some reason std::map::erase() returns void (MS will mess with your head on this one)

Comment: @Clay: Good point. I checked the standard, and that void return type is mandated there (23.1.2, Table 69), so it's not MS's fault. My guess is that the type is void so as not to force associative containers like map to do expensive lookup operations that will often be discarded. Since all associative containers are required to leave all other iterators valid upon insert() or erase() (23.1.2/8), there's actually no need to sneak a valid iterator back via the return value of erase().

Comment: Hmm. Clay's point means that unfortunately you can't write a single template function that deletes elements in both sequences (vectors, lists etc.) and associative containers (maps, sets, etc.) -- at least, not without resorting to template metaprogramming/type traits trickery. :/ One more reason to use remove()/remove_if() I guess.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: but remove()\remove_if() only works with sequences as well?

Answer (score 3):

Viktor's solution has the upside of being able to do something with the element before removing.  (I wasn't able to do this with `remove_if` or `remove_copy_if`.) But I prefer to use `std::find_if` so I never have to increment the iterator myself:

```
typedef vector<int> int_vector;
int_vector v;

int_vector::iterator itr = v.begin();
for(;;)
{
    itr = std::find_if(itr, v.end(), Predicate(4));
    if (itr == v.end())
    {
        break;
    }

    // do stuff with *itr here

    itr = v.erase(itr);  // grab a new, valid iterator
}
```

Where Predicate could be `bind1st( equal_to<int>(), 4 )` or something like this:

```
struct Predicate : public unary_function<int, bool>
{
    int mExpected;
    Predicate(int desired) : mExpected(desired) {}
    bool operator() (int input)
    {
        return ( input == mExpected );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer version with `while`:

```
typedef std::list<some_class_t> list_t;
void f( void ) {
  // Remove items from list
  list_t::iterator it = sample_list.begin();
  while ( it != sample_list.end() ) {
    if ( it->condition == true ) {
      it = sample_list.erase( it );
    } else ++it;    
  }
}
```

With `while` there is no danger to increment `it` twice as it could be in `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

1.For `std::vector<>` :

```
std::vector <int> vec;
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(), elem_to_remove), vec.end());
```

2.For `std::map<>` always use `std::map::erase()`

```
std::map<int,std::string> myMap;
myMap.emplace(std::make_pair(1, "Hello"));
myMap.emplace(std::make_pair(2, "Hi"));
myMap.emplace(std::make_pair(3, "How"));
myMap.erase( 1);//Erase with key
myMap.erase(myMap.begin(), ++myMap.begin() );//Erase with range
for( auto &ele: myMap)
{
    if(ele.first ==1)
    {
        myMap.erase(ele.first);//erase by key 
        break; //You can't use ele again properly 
               //wthin this iteration, so break.
    }
}
```

3. For `std::list` use `std::list::erase()`

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class Container, class Predicate>
void eraseIf( Container& container, Predicate predicate  ) {
    container.erase( remove_if( container.begin(), container.end(), predicate ), container.end() );
}   

// pre-c++11 version
template<class K, class V, class Predicate> 
void eraseIf( std::map<K,V>& container, Predicate predicate) {
    typename std::map<K,V>::iterator iter = container.begin();
    while(iter!=container.end()) { 
        iterator current = iter++;
        if(predicate(*current))
            container.erase(current);
    }
}

// c++11 version
template<class K, class V, class Predicate> 
void eraseIf( std::map<K,V>& container, Predicate predicate) {
    auto iter = container.begin();
    while(iter!=container.end()) {
        if(predicate(*iter))
            iter = container.erase(iter);
        else
            ++iter;
    }
}
```

Comment: The map version tries to increment an iterator after it's been erased (and is therefore invalid).

Comment: For the map version, you need this `if(cond) it = c.erase(it); else ++it;` .. and do NOT increment `it` in the `for` conventionally!

Comment: the original code predates C++11 and back in the old days, erase return type was void.
From what I can remember is that the iterator could not be dereferenced but could still be advanced.

Answer (score 1):

markh44 is the most STL-ish response.
Note, however, that in general, iterators are invalidated by modifying the container, but set and map are exceptions. There, you can remove items and still go on using the iterators, except if you delete the very item your iterator is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the post-decrement operator returns a copy of the iterator *before* it decrements.  Since the decremented iterator is still valid after erasing the current element, the for loop continues to operate as intended.

```
#include <list>
std::list<int> myList;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
{
   myList.push_back(i);
}

int cnt = 0;
for(std::list<int>::iterator iter = myList.begin(); iter != myList.end(); ++iter)
{
   if( cnt == 5 )
   {
      myList.erase(iter--);
   }
   ++cnt;
}
```

Edit: Doesn't work if you attempt to erase the first element in the list....