# C++ removing from list while iterating over list

Tags: c++, list

I have a `std::list` of `Bananas`, and I want to get rid of the bad ones.  Is there any *relatively* simple way to perform the following pseudocode?

```
foreach(Banana banana in bananaList)
{
    if(banana.isBad()) bananaList.remove(banana);
}
```

(Making a transition from C# and Java to C++ has been a rocky road.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038708/erase-remove-contents-from-the-map-or-any-other-stl-container-while-iterating

Comment: @YuppieNetworking: The linked question works in the general case, but doesn't have the best solution for the case the OP has -- where he wants to remove an element iff a member function returns true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bananaList.remove_if(std::mem_fun_ref(&Banana::isBad));
```

Note that you should probably be using `std::vector` instead of `std::list` though -- `vector` performs better in 99.9% of cases, and it's easier to work with.

EDIT: If you were using vectors, vectors don't have a remove_if member function, so you'd have to use the plain `remove_if` in namespace `std`:

```
bananaVector.erase(
    std::remove_if(bananaVector.begin(), bananaVector.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&Banana::isBad)), 
    bananaVector.end());
```

Comment: Really?  I thought that if I was removing lots of things from the middle of the list then `std::list` was the way to go.

Comment: @John: `std::list` makes the removal itself fast (O(1)), but finding the right spot relatively slow (O(N), usually a higher constant than vector).

Comment: @John: Due to better cache locality, in practice `std::vector` often performs better where, in theory, `std::list` does. You'll have to measure.

Comment: @Martin York: For `std::remove_if`, you would be correct. However, for `std::list<t>::remove_if` the member function takes care of that for you.

Comment: I can't quote the article, but I read something in Dr. Dobbs or the C++UJ where they did some massive tests on list, vector, set, etc..., and they found that almost every time vector was faster. Even when the vector was being resized or removes and inserts were happening in the middle, it was still much faster, thanks to the rules of cache locality.

Comment: You really have to be careful when saying that X always performs better than Y (not saying anybody did).  You need to understand to costs of the operations.  For example, if the copy constructor needed to move elements down in a vector is expensive, then a list could perform better.  In my own code, I've seen nice performance boosts by switching to vector.  Transient sets/maps can be very expensive to create and delete.

Comment: @Torlack: That's why I said "99.9%" of all cases. Because in 99% of cases it's true. Even in cases where there is an expensive constructor involved (i.e. `std::vector<std::wstring>`) vector usually performs better than list.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: That is why I said "not saying anybody did".  And I don't consider std::wstring constructor that expensive.  I was referring to much more complex objects.

Answer (score 1):

You'd typically do something like:

```
list.erase(std::remove_if(list.begin(), list.end(), std::mem_fun(Banana::isBad)), list.end());
```

Edit: Thanks to `remove_if` being implemented as a member function of `std::list`, Billy ONeal's answer is probably the better way to do the job as described, though this would be easier to convert when/if you decide to use a vector, deque, etc., which, as already discussed in comments, is probably a good thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a homebrew code like

```
for(list<...>::iterator it=bananas.begin(); end=bananas.end(); it!=end;) {
  if(... decide ...) {
    it=bananas.erase(it);
  } else
    ++it;
}
```

or, you can use the [`list::remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/remove_if/) method, or [`std::remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) function (which is usable with a `vector`, too).

Comment: One should always prefer algorithms to explicit loops.