# How to remove from a map while iterating it?

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11

How do I remove from a map while iterating it? like:

```
std::map<K, V> map;
for(auto i : map)
    if(needs_removing(i))
        // remove it from the map
```

If I use `map.erase` it will invalidate the iterators

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038708/erase-remove-contents-from-the-map-or-any-other-stl-container-while-iterating

Comment: Even more similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800955/remove-if-equivalent-for-stdmap

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180516/how-to-filter-items-from-a-stdmap

Comment: On the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to

Answer (score 391, accepted):

The standard associative-container erase idiom:

```
for (auto it = m.cbegin(); it != m.cend() /* not hoisted */; /* no increment */)
{
  if (must_delete)
  {
    m.erase(it++);    // or "it = m.erase(it)" since C++11
  }
  else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Note that we really want an ordinary `for` loop here, since we are modifying the container itself. The range-based loop should be strictly reserved for situations where we only care about the elements. The syntax for the RBFL makes this clear by not even exposing the container inside the loop body.

**Edit.** Pre-C++11, you could not erase const-iterators. There you would have to say:

```
for (std::map<K,V>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ) { /* ... */ }
```

Erasing an element from a container is not at odds with constness of the element. By analogy, it has always been perfectly legitimate to `delete p` where `p` is a pointer-to-constant. Constness does not constrain lifetime; const values in C++ can still stop existing.

Comment: "not even exposing the container inside the loop body" what do you mean?

Comment: @Dani: Well, contrast this to the 20th-century construction `for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)`. Here we have to say `v[i]` inside the loop, i.e. we must explicitly mention the container. The RBFL on the other hand introduces the loop variable that is directly usable as the value, and so no knowledge of the container is required inside the loop. This is a clue to the intended usage of the RBFL for loops that do *not* have to know about the container. Erasing is the complete opposite situation, where it's all about the container.

Comment: @skyhisi: Just saw myself that and fixed it, thanks! I had it mixed up in my mind with the sequence-erase idiom where you say `it = v.erase(it);` (no `++`). It'll never happen again, promise.

Comment: @MooingDuck the [map (C++) Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C%2B%2B%29) states: "Iterators and references are not invalidated by insert and erase operations, except for iterators and references to erased elements."

Comment: @skyhisi: Indeed. This is one of the legitimate uses of the post-increment: *First* increment `it` to get the next, valid iterator, and *then* erase the old one. It doesn't work the other way round!

Comment: @skyhisi: I was thinking that the erase/rebalance might cause it to skip a node, but then realized it always iterates in order, so even a rebalance will not cause it to magically skip one.  This algorithm is safe.

Comment: can't this just be a while instead of a for?

Comment: I read somewhere that in C++11, `it = v.erase(it);` now works for maps too.That is, erase() on *all* associative elements now returns the next iterator. So the old kludge that required a post-increment++ within the delete(), is no longer needed. This (if true) is a Good Thing, as the kludge relied on overridden-post-increment-within-a-function-call magic, "fixed" by newbie maintainers to take the increment out of the function call, or to swap it to a preincrement "because that's just a style thing", etc.

Comment: why would you call `it++` in the `if` _and_ `else` blocks? wouldn't it be enough to call it once _after_ these?

Comment: Code does not work.  The erase line should be: `it = m.erase(it);`.  The proposed line causes an infinite loop.

Comment: @PauloCarvalho: Hm, the code [works for me](http://ideone.com/Leyjif)...

Comment: Use with care:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965452/crash-in-c-stdmap/39011211

Comment: @StepanYakovenko: That code looks... somewhat questionable. I don't think that's related to this answer.

Comment: Why not hoist the `end()` iterator here? There can't be no invalidation, can there?

Comment: @TemplateRex: Good question, I'm not actually sure. I think I just wrote the code for both associative and sequence containers and didn't adapt it to the additional guarantees for associative containers. (But I'd have to check those.)

Comment: Just got the question from this [linked Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381183/is-it-good-practise-to-increment-or-decrement-the-loop-counter-inside-a-for-loop?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: `m.erase(it++);` -- doesn't this invalidate the iterator before it gets incremented?  It may work in practice, due to the particular implementation of the map, but it doesn't seem kosher according to the docs.  For that reason, I prefer the second answer by @d-coetzee

Comment: @Ewat: No, that's fine.It's the *erasing* that invalidates the erased iterator; the increment happens before the erasing. This is a poster-child example of the use of post-increment.

Comment: @nburk And by that token itsn't it equivalent to just use the normal three-element for loop pattern where the increment happens in the third statement? https://ideone.com/W36yag

Comment: `it = m.erase(it);` is valid for all containers (now, although it wasn't always in the past).  `m.erase(it++);` is valid **only** for containers that guarantee that only the erased iterator and no other iterators are invalidated on erase operations (which includes std::map but not std::vector; ymmv for other containers).  So the posted code is correct for std::map and should be correct for _most_ associative containers, but not necessarily all (e.g. it's very likely to be wrong for a flat_map).  To be safe you should use the variant in the comment unless you can't use C++11.

Comment: What about during reverse iteration, there is a compiler error? Edit: nvm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830158/how-to-call-erase-with-a-reverse-iterator

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow: Change `it->second == "bar"` to `it->second == "foo"` and you [get a segfault](https://ideone.com/QMXRGr
). The iterator pointing to the erased item is invalided by `erase()`, so you need to do `++it` or `it = m.erase(it)`.

Answer (score 63):

I personally prefer this pattern which is slightly clearer and simpler, at the expense of an extra variable:

```
for (auto it = m.cbegin(), next_it = it; it != m.cend(); it = next_it)
{
  ++next_it;
  if (must_delete)
  {
    m.erase(it);
  }
}
```

Advantages of this approach:

- the for loop incrementor makes sense as an incrementor;
- the erase operation is a simple erase, rather than being mixed in with increment logic;
- after the first line of the loop body, the meaning of `it` and `next_it` remain fixed throughout the iteration, allowing you to easily add additional statements referring to them without headscratching over whether they will work as intended (except of course that you cannot use `it` after erasing it).

Comment: I can think of another advantage actually, if the loop calls into code which erases that entry being iterated over or previous ones (and the loop is unaware of it) it will work without any harm done. The only restriction is whether something is erasing what is being pointed to by next_it or successors. A totally cleared list/map can be tested against as well.

Comment: This answer is simple and clear, even if the loop is more complex and has multiple levels of logic to decide whether or not to delete, or do other various tasks. I've proposed an edit, though, to make it a little simpler. "next_it" can be set to "it" in the for's init to avoid typos, and since the the init and iteration statements both set it and next_it to the same values, you don't need to say "next_it = it;" at the start of the loop.

Comment: Keep in mind anyone who uses this answer: You must have "++next_it" inside the for loop, and not in the iteration expression. If you try to move it into the iteration expression as "it = next_it++", then on the last iteration, when "it" is going to be set equal to "m.cend()", you will attempt to iterate "next_it" past "m.cend()", which is erroneous.

Comment: I see all the advantages as disadvantages.

Answer (score 15):

C++20 has a convenience overload of [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) for `std::map`.

So you can use that function to do it as a one-liner.

```
std::map<K, V> map_obj;

// calls needs_removing for each element and erases it, if true was returned
std::erase_if(map_obj, needs_removing);

// if you need to pass only part of the key/value pair
std::erase_if(map_obj, [] (auto& kv) { return needs_removing(kv.first); });
```

Answer (score 11):

Assuming C++11, here is a one-liner loop body, if this is consistent with your programming style:

```
using Map = std::map<K,V>;
Map map;

// Erase members that satisfy needs_removing(itr)
for (Map::const_iterator itr = map.cbegin() ; itr != map.cend() ; )
  itr = needs_removing(itr) ? map.erase(itr) : std::next(itr);
```

A couple of other minor style changes:

- Show declared type (`Map::const_iterator`) when possible/convenient, over using `auto`.
- Use `using` for template types, to make ancillary types (`Map::const_iterator`) easier to read/maintain.

Comment: is it possible that this causes a memory leak? It does in my case. But really not sure why.

Comment: Not any more than the other answers. I'd look for the memory leak in or involving the destructor(s) for the `std::map` key and/or value types.

Answer (score 8):

In short "How do I remove from a map while iterating it?"

- With old map impl: You can't
- With new map impl: almost as @KerrekSB suggested. But there are some syntax issues in what he posted.

From GCC map impl (note **GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X**):

```
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // DR 130. Associative erase should return an iterator.
      /**
       *  @brief Erases an element from a %map.
       *  @param  position  An iterator pointing to the element to be erased.
       *  @return An iterator pointing to the element immediately following
       *          @a position prior to the element being erased. If no such 
       *          element exists, end() is returned.
       *
       *  This function erases an element, pointed to by the given
       *  iterator, from a %map.  Note that this function only erases
       *  the element, and that if the element is itself a pointer,
       *  the pointed-to memory is not touched in any way.  Managing
       *  the pointer is the user's responsibility.
       */
      iterator
      erase(iterator __position)
      { return _M_t.erase(__position); }
#else
      /**
       *  @brief Erases an element from a %map.
       *  @param  position  An iterator pointing to the element to be erased.
       *
       *  This function erases an element, pointed to by the given
       *  iterator, from a %map.  Note that this function only erases
       *  the element, and that if the element is itself a pointer,
       *  the pointed-to memory is not touched in any way.  Managing
       *  the pointer is the user's responsibility.
       */
      void
      erase(iterator __position)
      { _M_t.erase(__position); }
#endif
```

Example with old and new style:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
typedef map<int, int> t_myMap;
typedef vector<t_myMap::key_type>  t_myVec;

int main() {

    cout << "main() ENTRY" << endl;

    t_myMap mi;
    mi.insert(t_myMap::value_type(1,1));
    mi.insert(t_myMap::value_type(2,1));
    mi.insert(t_myMap::value_type(3,1));
    mi.insert(t_myMap::value_type(4,1));
    mi.insert(t_myMap::value_type(5,1));
    mi.insert(t_myMap::value_type(6,1));

    cout << "Init" << endl;
    for(t_myMap::const_iterator i = mi.begin(); i != mi.end(); i++)
        cout << '\t' << i->first << '-' << i->second << endl;

    t_myVec markedForDeath;

    for (t_myMap::const_iterator it = mi.begin(); it != mi.end() ; it++)
        if (it->first > 2 && it->first < 5)
            markedForDeath.push_back(it->first);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < markedForDeath.size(); i++)
        // old erase, returns void...
        mi.erase(markedForDeath[i]);

    cout << "after old style erase of 3 & 4.." << endl;
    for(t_myMap::const_iterator i = mi.begin(); i != mi.end(); i++)
        cout << '\t' << i->first << '-' << i->second << endl;

    for (auto it = mi.begin(); it != mi.end(); ) {
        if (it->first == 5)
            // new erase() that returns iter..
            it = mi.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    }

    cout << "after new style erase of 5" << endl;
    // new cend/cbegin and lambda..
    for_each(mi.cbegin(), mi.cend(), [](t_myMap::const_reference it){cout << '\t' << it.first << '-' << it.second << endl;});

    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
main() ENTRY
Init
        1-1
        2-1
        3-1
        4-1
        5-1
        6-1
after old style erase of 3 & 4..
        1-1
        2-1
        5-1
        6-1
after new style erase of 5
        1-1
        2-1
        6-1

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.021 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is the problem with `mi.erase(it++);` ?

Comment: @lvella see op. "If I use map.erase it will invalidate the iterators".

Comment: Your new method will not work if after erasing, the map becomes empty. In that case, the iterator will be invalidated. So, soon after erasing, its better to insert `if(mi.empty()) break;`.

Answer (score 5):

Pretty sad, eh?  The way I usually do it is build up a container of iterators instead of deleting during traversal.  Then loop through the container and use map.erase()

```
std::map<K,V> map;
std::list< std::map<K,V>::iterator > iteratorList;

for(auto i : map ){
    if ( needs_removing(i)){
        iteratorList.push_back(i);
    }
}
for(auto i : iteratorList){
    map.erase(*i)
}
```

Comment: But after erasing one the rest will be invalid

Comment: Nope: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263945/what-happens-if-you-call-erase-on-a-map-element-while-iterating-from-begin-to

Comment: @Dani: Not in a map. Erasure in map only invalidates iterator to the erased item.