# Getting run time error between cross- plateform with same C++ code

Tags: c++, stl, cross-platform

I am erasing element from the C++ multimap using following code which is running perfectly under Linux, but throwing expression set/map is not incrementable on Windows.

```
void delete_entries(multimap<int, pair<int, int> > &m, int i, int j) {
    // This function deletes entries from multimap where box number == i and Ball index ==j

    multimap<int, pair<int, int> > ::iterator it = m.begin();
    while (it != m.end()) {
        if ((*it).second.first == i || (*it).second.second == j)
            m.erase(it);
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are ignoring the [iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: @NathanOliver i know problem in code but my question why it run on linux but not running in windows.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  It can do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (it != m.end()) {
    if ((*it).second.first == i || (*it).second.second == j)
        m.erase(it);
    it++;   //if the previous condition holds true, 'it' is invalidated
}
```

An erased iterator becomes invalidated. And incrementing an invalidated iterator is Undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior means that even if it *seemingly works*, there are no more guarantees to the behavior of your entire program. *(this applies to the seemingly working one in linux too; you should be really happy that it crashed on MSVC)*

For the correct way to erase, see the other answers here and this question: [How to remove from a map while iterating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it)

Answer (score 2):

Since C++11, erase returns the iterator following the last removed element.

```
void delete_entries(multimap<int, pair<int, int> > &m, int i, int j) {
// this function deletes entries from multimap where box number == i and Ball index ==j 

  multimap<int, pair<int, int> > ::iterator it = m.begin();
  while (it != m.end()) {
    if ((*it).second.first == i || (*it).second.second == j)
      it = m.erase(it);
    else
      it++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The iterator becomes invalid after erase. Since C++11, you can do:

```
while (it != m.end()) {
    if ((*it).second.first == i || (*it).second.second == j)
        it = m.erase(it);
    else
        it++;
}
```