# C++ rend() points to the same element as rbegin()

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

Running the code below, I would expect to see a different address for the 4th value of test 1 (not the same as values 1 and 3). This shows that rend() is the same as rbegin() ??
I also would not expect the loop to go through a second iteration and get a segfault.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
map<unsigned long, int*> newMap;
newMap[13] = new int(1340);
cout << "test 1:" << endl;
cout << &(*(newMap.begin())) << endl;
cout << &(*(newMap.end())) << endl;
cout << &(*(newMap.rbegin())) << endl;
cout << &(*(newMap.rend())) << endl;
cout << "test 2:" << endl;
for(map<unsigned long, int*>::reverse_iterator it=newMap.rbegin();it!=newMap.rend();){
  cout << "next iteration" << endl;
  map<unsigned long, int*>::reverse_iterator entry = it;
  it++;
  delete entry->second;
  newMap.erase(entry->first);
}
```

Output:

```
test 1:
0x2299050
0x7fffcd574908
0x2299050
0x2299050
test 2:
next iteration
next iteration
*** glibc detected *** ./foo: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000002299030 ***
```

EDIT: Here's an updated/simplified version, still with the same problem (test 2 only); this doesn't cause a segfault because it's not using pointers, but still goes through the loop twice:

```
map<int, int> newMap;
newMap[13] = 1340;
cout << "test 2:" << endl;
for(map<int, int>::reverse_iterator it=newMap.rbegin();it!=newMap.rend();){
  cout << "next iteration" << endl;
  int index = it->first;
  int value = it->second;
  it++;
  newMap.erase(index);
}
```

Comment: De-referencing `end()` or `rend()` is UB as they represent the *past-the-end* iterators.

Comment: BTW `newMap[13] = new int(1340);` are you sure?

Comment: That explains test 1, but how about test 2? I added a simplified example at the end

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes I meant to point to a single int, but that's not the point of the question anyway so I modified it to be a value instead of a pointer.

Comment: test 2: not sure you can modify a map while you're iterating over it, reverse or not.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it).

Comment: you're not using the same code at all!

Answer (score 0):

In test 1, you are dereferencing the past-the-end iterators.  As mentioned by ArchbishopOfBanterbury in the comments, the results of this are undefined.

In test 2, you are invalidating `it` by erasing the element pointed to by `it.base()`.  [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) holds an iterator to the next element (so `newMap.rbegin()` holds an iterator equal to `newMap.end()` and `newMap.rend()` holds an iterator equal to `newMap.begin()`).

When you increment `it`, it becomes equal to `newMap.rend()`, meaning that `it.base()` is equal to `newMap.begin()`.  You then erase the element referenced by `it.base()`, which invalidates `it.base()` thereby invalidating `it` as well.  Since `it` is now invalid, comparing it to `newMap.rend()` doesn't work.