# Iterator invalid read of size 4

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, valgrind

Why might Valgrind indicate `Invalid read of size 4` in the following line?

```
for (map<uint16_t, SPacket *>::iterator it = m_PacketMap.begin() ; it != m_PacketMap.end(); ++it) 
{
    if (it->first < ackNumber)
    {
        if (it->second->data) delete [] it->second->data;
        if (it->second) delete it->second;
        m_PacketMap.erase(it);
    }
}
```

I verify that `m_PacketMap.size() > 0` before the loop and have temporarily added debug before the loop to verify the m_PacketMap contents but it all looks as expected. This is the Valgrind error message and RadioManager.cpp:1042 is the line above:

```
==5535== Invalid read of size 4
==5535==    at 0x421EBE5: std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base*) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==5535==    by 0x80AD20D: RadioManager::DecodeAcknowledgementNumber(unsigned char*, unsigned int) (RadioManager.cpp:1042)
```

This is how SPacket and m_PacketMap are defined

```
typedef struct SPacket
{
    uint8_t * data;
    size_t size;
    timeval tval;
} SPacket;
map<uint16_t, SPacket *> m_PacketMap;
```

Is there an issue with my iterator, a possible issue in _Rb_tree_increment, or something else entirely?

Comment: Yes. I am erasing map entries if they match the key. I'll add the body to the original question. Ah. I think I see what you are getting at. How can the iterator work when the container is shrinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erasing container elements from a `for` loop has to be done with care...

You must do:

```
map<uint16_t, SPacket *>::iterator it = m_PacketMap.begin()
while ( it != m_PacketMap.end() ) 
{
    if (it->first < ackNumber)
    {
        if (it->second->data) delete [] it->second->data;
        if (it->second) delete it->second;
        // it updated by erase, no need to increment
        it = m_PacketMap.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        // move to next item
        ++it;
    }
}
```

That's the way a loop removing some elements of a container must be written (works the same for set, vector...).

For maps, code above only works from C++11. If you use an earlier version, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234813/3336423) (not tested), you should do:

```
for ( map<uint16_t, SPacket *>::iterator it = m_PacketMap.begin(); it != m_PacketMap.end();  ) 
{
    if (it->first < ackNumber)
    {
        if (it->second->data) delete [] it->second->data;
        if (it->second) delete it->second;
        // it updated by erase, no need to increment
        m_PacketMap.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
        // move to next item
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Because erasing the item and then incrementing it (what you end up doing with your `for` loop) will make you loose elements and possible pass over `m_PacketMap.end()` (and then have your loop cover items out of container's limits) if you erase the last element from the container.

Comment: m_SentPacketMap was a typo

Comment: Should the `m_PacketMap.erase(it++)` be `m_PacketMap.erase(it)`?

Comment: `it = m_PacketMap.erase(it);` for C++11, `m_PacketMap.erase(it++);` for earlier versions (`it = m_PacketMap.erase(it);` should not compile then)

Answer (score 1):

You erase an element, which makes `it` invalid, then you increment `it`. You cannot increment an invalid iterator.

Rebuilding your code with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` would enable the libstdc++ Debug Mode, which would abort on an invalid iterator operation.

Unrelated to the valgrind error, you do not need to test the pointers are not null before using `delete`, because it is safe to use `delete` on a null pointer (it checks for null anyway, so you're just adding unnecessary duplicate checks).