# Erase an element from a map then put it back

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

Suppose I have a backtracking algorithm where I need to remove an element from a map, do something, then put it back. I am not sure if there is a good way to do it:

```
func(std::<K, V> map &dict) {
    for (auto i : dict) {
       remove i from dict;
       func(dict);
       put i back to dict;
    }
}
```

I know there are ways to delete an element from map in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it) but I am not sure if there are ways to achieve what I described above. I am aware that I can create a new dict in for loop and pass it in func but I am wondering if it can be done using the same dict.

Comment: An example in actual c++ would be helpful to illustrate your question. I'm pretty sure every line that isn't a single brace contains a syntax or logic error.

Comment: One does not modify the container they are iterating. (Just a guideline, of course there are exceptions)

Comment: The `remove i from dict;` step will invalidate the iterator your range-for is holding under the hood.

Comment: sounds like a `stack` of `pairs`?

Comment: There are many ways to do this ... what's appropriate depends on the map size, and mostly on how `func` is using your map...

Comment: What about leaving the object in the map, but marking it with a "disabled" flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask is definitely possible.  Here is one way to do it while trying to keep things simple and efficient:

```
void func(std::map<K, V> &dict) {
    for (auto i = dict.cbegin(); i != dict.cend(); ) {
       auto old = *i;
       i = dict.erase(i);   // i now points to the next element (or dict.end())
       some_other_func(dict);
       dict.insert(i, old); // i is used a hint where to re-insert the old value
    }
}
```

By calling `std::map::erase` with an iterator argument and `std::map::insert` with a hint, the complexity of each iteration through this loop is amortized constant.  Note that I assumed your calling of `func` in line 5 was actually supposed to be `some_other_func`, because calling `func` recursively would invalidate the iterator you carefully set in line 4.

However, this is not the most efficient way to do this sort of processing (@rakurai has a [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44423861/5075720) that should be considered).

Comment: When you call some_other_func(dict) do you mean pass a copy of dict to the some_other_func? I hope to call the same function (func) recursively. I am not sure why it invalidates the iterator since I am trying to keep the dict the same as the state it is passed in in each iteration of for loop. Could you please explain more about this? What if I want to call func in the for loop recursively? Is passing by copy the only way?

Comment: After `i = dict.erase(i);`, the iterator points to the next element in the map, which is why no increment is needed in the `for` statement.  If `func` were called recursively (and the signature still used a reference), when the inner `func` erases what the outer `func` calls `i`, that would invalidate the outer `i`, so the next step through the `for` loop outside the recursive call would probably core dump.  If the signature were `func(std::map<K,V> dict)` (no ampersand), then the map would be copied on each recursive call. This would incur a significant performance penalty, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

This question has an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it).

However, your problem may be that you would like the function to *ignore* the key K while processing dict.  How about a second parameter "K ignore" and make the function skip that pair?  You could give it a default value in the declaration if that breaks other code, or overload the function.