# std::map to std::list leads to SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, stdmap, segmentation-fault, stdlist

I want to save RAM while converting a std::map to a std::list. Therefore I have to delete every element in between. But I get a SIGSEGV.

```
template <class U>
auto ConvertFlatSegmentsMapToList(std::map<std::string /* relative_path */, U>& differences_map, std::list<U>& differences_list) -> void {
    for (auto& i:differences_map) {
        differences_list.push_back(i.second);
        // differences_map.erase(i.first);//TODO: SIGSEGV
    }
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: When I clear after the for loop, I don't save RAM. i want wo copy one by one and delete in between to save RAM.

Comment: This should help so you can delete while iterating: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234813/1142788

Comment: @yussuf: Thank you. I have added an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yussuf commented, you can find the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234813/1142788. I have adapted this to my example. (needs c++11 support)

```
template <class U>
auto ConvertFlatSegmentsMapToList(std::map<std::string /* relative_path */, U>& differences_map, std::list<U>& differences_list) -> void {
    std::clog << "differences_map: " << differences_map.size() << std::endl;    // e.g. 6
    std::clog << "differences_list: " << differences_list.size() << std::endl;  // e.g. 0

    for (auto i = differences_map.cbegin(); i != differences_map.cend(); i = differences_map.erase(i)) {
        differences_list.push_back(i->second);
    }

    std::clog << "differences_map: " << differences_map.size() << std::endl;    // e.g. 0
    std::clog << "differences_list: " << differences_list.size() << std::endl;  // e.g. 6
}
```

Comment: Because `std::map::erase()` returns a (valid) iterator?  Neat.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to save memory, don't use `std::map`, nor `std::list` - use `std::vector`; or better yet - don't use separate strings, apply de-duplication etc.

Having said that, and to answer your question: Deleting an element from a map [invalidates iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules/6438087#6438087) into the map - and the ranged-for loop is actually based on iterators. So  - you can't delete during your loop. Use `differences_map.clear()` after the loop. You should also note that individual element deletions are much more expensive time-wise than clearing the entire map.

If your memory is so constrained that you can't take having both the full map and the full list at the same time, then you are simply using the wrong data structures - since, like I said, both of these are quite wasteful. Still, if you insist, you could repeatedly insert `*differences_map.begin()` into the list, then delete it from the map (and every time obtain `.begin()` again, after iterator invalidation).

Comment: That is no answer to my question. You cann't use a vector in any case. I use a map becuse I need a map. But after that I need something that is smaller and is sortable. If I have a map witch 100 MB and create a list with 100 MB, than this is waste of RAM if I don't need the map any more.

Comment: @B.A.Sylla: A vector is quite sortable, I'm not sure what you mean. Plus, there's more than one way to implement a map; and if your map values are small, the overheads of `std::map` are quite significant. Anyway, when you `clear()` the map it stops using all of its memory.

Comment: @einpoklum Too late!  You already made a second copy of it all.

Comment: @PaulSanders: So? OP didn't say there's not enough memory for that.

Comment: @einpoklum See OP's first comment to his own question.  Could've been worded more clearly, but that was my reading of it.

Comment: @PaulSanders: See my edit. Actually, in hind sight, this whole thing is an XY problem and we should have just coaxed OP to say what he really wants to do.

Comment: Yes, could be .

Answer (score 0):

You could consider storing `std::shared_ptr`s in your `map`, `list` or whatever.  Then you can copy them around cheaply and easily without the need to copy the underlying data.  You still get (more-or-less) value semantics, and should not need to manage object lifetimes manually.

Comment: This is true when speed is more important than memory. Pointers need memory.

Comment: @B.A.Sylla Not enough to matter, see [live demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RltdBHZCR8kXU6R7).