# erase set element while iterating///

Tags: c++

I don't understand, why it is runtime error?
Erase set element while iterating.

```
set<int> sset;
sset.insert(3);
sset.insert(5);
sset.insert(6);

for(auto s: sset){
    sset.erase(s);
}
```

Comment: if you want to do it correctly, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234813/1142788

Comment: @MikeBorkland: erase-remove idiom doesn't apply to `std::set`

Comment: `sset.clear()` does the job currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just to explain further,

What you effectively have written is:

```
for (set<int>::const_iterator i=sset.begin(), e=sset.end(); i != e; i++)
{
    auto s = *i;
    sset.erase(s);
}
```

So the issue is that on doing the erase, the internal iterator `i` becomes invalidated. This is a general pain with trying to sequentially delete the content of many of the containers.

The following more traditional sequential delete code is also bad for the same reason, but perhaps more obviously:

```
for (set<int>::iterator i=sset.begin(), e=sset.end(); i != e; i++)
{
    sset.erase(i);
}
```

**Fixes:**

Generally, it is simpler to rely on context swap destruction of the whole container, when you can:

```
C++98: SsetType().swap(sset); 
C++11: sset = decltype<sset>();
```

And you could just do:

```
sset.erase(sset.begin(), sset.end());
```

Another way to fix this is to just keep deleting the `begin()` until the set is `empty()`

But the problem with all of these is you can't easily extend them to conditionally erase members of a set you are iterating through. Yes, there are helpers for conditional erase as well, and they can be used with lambdas, so they can carry state, but they generally tend to be as hard to use as rolling your own loop.

Since c++11, set::erase(iterator) returns a new iterator which is safe to continue iterating with, so you can write:

```
for (set<int>::iterator i=sset.begin(), e=sset.end(); i != e; )
{
    i = sset.erase(i);
}
```

If you were performing some conditional test, then:

```
for (set<int>::iterator i=sset.begin(), e=sset.end(); i != e; )
{
    if ( ... condition ... )
        i = sset.erase(i);
    else
        i++;
}
```

before, in c++98, you would have written something like:

```
for (set<int>::iterator i=sset.begin(), e=sset.end(); i != e; )
{
    auto j = i;
    j++;
    if ( ... condition ... )
        i = sset.erase(i);
    i = j;
}
```

As an exercise, you can roll the use of `j` into the `for` statement. getting the initial j++ in C98 is tricky, though!

Comment: Are you *sure* the first snippet should have a `const_iterator`?

Comment: You should use `auto`

Comment: @Mohit: Why?͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: @Bathsheba It'll automatically identify the type of the variable. You need not to type such a long type names.

Comment: @Mohit: That's not necessarily a bad thing. Using `auto` in old-style `for` loops can get you into trouble if the type of an object is changed by an errant refactorer.

Comment: @Bathsheba: anyway "`key`" cannot be modified so `const_iterator` and `iterator` are mostly equivalent for `std::set`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Of course, you're correct. I'll upvote the question for good feelings and refrain from trolling for a while.

Comment: I wanted to spell out exactly what was happening under the hood (well as close as is useful) so wanted to avoid auto. How would using auto have helped explain what was going on? As to const, yes, perhaps the true implementation does not use const so that it can support non-const-ref, but it seemed correct to the usage. As @Jarod42 says, it is irrelevant for set, anyway, just personal stylee.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, erasing elements from `sset` will *invalidate* the implicit iteration over the container; that's used by the nice syntactic sugar `auto s : sset`.

That's *undefined behaviour*.