# map::erase sometimes does not erase the entry from the map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm having a sporadic problem right now where map::erase() says it worked, but the map sometimes still has the element in it.

```
auto iterator = device_map.begin();  // std::map<std::string,Device*>
size_t nDeleted = 0;
while (iterator != map.end()) {
    Device* device = device_map[iterator->first];
    if (device->done()) {
        device->close();
        cout << "Erasing " << iterator->first << endl;
        nDeleted = device_map.erase(iterator->first);
        delete device;
    }
    ++iterator;
}
```

This is called in a std::thread every 500ms. I've tested it by printing the contents of the map before and after the loop, like this:

```
cout << "device_map = ";
for (std::map<string, Device*>::iterator it = device_map.begin(); it != device_map.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << " = " << it->second << "; ";
}
cout << endl;
```

Sometimes, even if nDeleted == 1, the contents of device_map is the same before and after unmapping the element (except that *device == nullptr because of the delete).

I've also put a breakpoint and device_map.size() is indeed unchanged after calling device_map.erase() does not work.

I have tried this other version of map::erase with the same results:

```
auto iterator = device_map.begin();  // std::map<std::string,Device*>
size_t nDeleted = 0;
while (iterator != map.end()) {
    Device* device = device_map[iterator->first];
    if (device->done()) {
        device->close();
        cout << "Erasing " << iterator->first << endl;
        iterator = device_map.erase(iterator);
        delete device;
    } else {
        ++iterator;
    }
}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Thank you,

Fred

Comment: You're deleting your elements whilst iterating over your map, once you delete an entry you invalidate the iterator. Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it. Basically your map has to re-sort once you modify the contents

Comment: `Device* device = device_map[iterator->first];` This is silly. You should use `... = iterator->second`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `device_map.erase(iterator->first);` also "great" approach, especially that `device_map.erase(iterator)` would compile.

Comment: @EdChum, the code updates the iterator correctly: iterator = device_map.erase(iterator); and tests equality with end() called every time. I believe the looping/editing is fine

Comment: @fchasse, did you try putting the whole loop into a mutex ? Are you sure you have a single thread playing with this data at once?

Comment: @Jeffrey I was looking at the first code snippet, the second snippet does seem fine though. Maybe this is a synchronisation issue

Comment: You wouldn’t happen to be using the map in a different thread as well?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  We don't even know if the map you're erasing from is the actual map you want to erase from.  There are many questions here where a *copy* of the map is being worked with instead of the original, thus any changes to the original are not being done.

Comment: Not a duplicate, as discussed in the comments above. Second snippet is fine as far as deletion go.

Comment: @Jeffrey I will try, but this specific map is used by only one thread

Comment: Then something doesn't add up. Is it possible that device::done(), device::close() or device::~device() calls indirectly back into this code, or into anything that changes the map?

Comment: @Jeffrey Actually, the map itself might be accessed by another thread _while_ map::erase is being called, would that explain the issue?

There is a function in another thread that uses map::find and map::end, and I think it's possible that it happens during the erase

Comment: It could explain the issue. std::map is not thread-safe on non-const operations

Comment: I will add a mutex and post back the results

Comment: It seems that adding a mutex solved the issue, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeffrey suggested, the issue was with another thread accessing the std::map object while map::erase was being called. Adding a mutex solved the problem.