# C++ map not deleting elements

Tags: c++, ordered-map

Given a target K, and an array of distinct elements, the task is to remove all pairs from the array which sums to K.

This is the approach I followed

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    cin>>array[i];
cin>>K;
map<int, int> mp;
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if(mp.find(array[i])==mp.end())
        mp[array[i]] = 1;
    else
        mp[array[i]]++;
}
```

Logic for deletion

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   if(mp[K-array[i]]>0)
   {            
       mp.erase(K-array[i]);
       mp.erase(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Print output :

```
cout<<mp.size();
```

Input :

```
array = 6 5 4 2 1 0
K = 6
```

Program output

```
4
```

Expected Output

```
0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove from a map while iterating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234779/how-to-remove-from-a-map-while-iterating-it)

Comment: I am sorry, I am a beginner I did not understand what mistake am I making

Comment: Please, make a minimal example so we can reproduce the problem (so include `main` function, all `include` statements etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mp[K-array[i]]>0)
```

`std::map::operator::[]` will add if element doesn't exists

You will have to find and remove like following:

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
   if(mp.find(K-array[i]) != mp.end()  && 
      K-array[i] != array[i])
      //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ check required to see k/2 = array[i]
      // Note: all numbers are distinct 
   { 
       mp.erase(K-array[i]);
       mp.erase(array[i]);
   }
}
```

---

A better strategy would be to use remove elements during scanning using `std::unordered_set`

```
std::unordered_set<int> s;

for(const auto& ele: array) {
    auto it =  s.find( K - ele);
    if ( it == s.end() ) {
     s.insert(ele);   
    } else {
        s.erase(it);
    }
}

std::cout << s.size();
```

See [<kbd>here</kbd>](https://rextester.com/ROLSBT41676)

Comment: Downvoters please explain. I will be happy to update and remove.

Comment: First solution is wrong!! For Array [6, 0] it will remove 6 and 0

Comment: @user2407394 https://rextester.com/ROM44551 
_"the task is to remove all pairs from the array which sums to K."_  isn't  6+0 =6 ?

Comment: In first solution you need to take into account the number of occurrence of same element.

Comment: Only use `erase` when the `m[elem]` becomes 0. Otherwise, decrement the counters of both elements by the minimum of them and erase the minimum. Also, erase all occurrences of `K/2` except one if exists.