# C++ - begin() returns the end() iterator with a non-empty list

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

As the question suggest, I'm having a very strange behavior with iterators and lists.
So, the (class) problem asks for a function that erase all elements that meet a condition from a list and, when I tried to cover the case where I have a list where all elements are the same I found out that the last element persisted.

Here is the code:

```
void esborra_tots(list<Estudiant>& t, int x) {
    list<Estudiant>::iterator it;
    list<Estudiant>::iterator itend = t.end();

    for (it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it).consultar_DNI() == x) {

            t.erase(it);
            if (t.empty()) return;
            else it = t.begin();
        }
    }
}
```

I've used *itend* just to see the value while debugging.
Here is the session:
[image: See that the list *t* is not empty but t.begin() returns the same as t.end()]

How is this possible? 
PD: I'm not searching for other approaches to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're doing `it++` (the loop post-action) after your `it = t.begin()`.

Remove that, and stick an `else it++` (though I prefer `++it`) in your loop body; it needs to only happen when you *don't* do the erasure.

This is similar to the method for [erasing from a `map` while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234813/4386278).

Taking a cue from that method, we can notice that your `else it = t.begin()` is wasteful: you're starting from the beginning of the loop every time, which increases the algorithmic complexity of your algorithm.

Instead, use [the iterator returned by `erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase).

```
void esborra_tots(list<Estudiant>& t, int x) {
    list<Estudiant>::iterator it;
    list<Estudiant>::iterator itend = t.end();

    for (it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); ) {
        if ((*it).consultar_DNI() == x) {
            it = t.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how we also no longer need to check the list for emptiness; if it's now empty, `it` will be `t.end()` and the loop will end anyway.

---

Currently, you're not using `itend`. You can't just swap it into the loop condition, for obvious reasons, but if you reset it when it gets invalidated then it could be worthwhile:

```
void esborra_tots(list<Estudiant>& t, int x) {
    for (auto it = t.begin(), end = t.end(); it != end; ) {
        if (it->consultar_DNI() == x) {
            it = t.erase(it);
            end = t.end();
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it may be clearer to just stick with your original code but remove the unused `itend` declaration.

Comment: Or avoid all this and use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) like `t.remove_if([x](const auto& elem) { return elem.consultar_DNI() == x; })`.  Still, +1

Comment: That was very useful!! 
Not having teachers due to the quarantine it's a real problem!

Comment: @NathanOliver Or that, though I kinda find the written-out loop clearer. Also tbh for a `list` I'd be curious to know what the performance comparison is like

Comment: AFAIK, `list::remove_if` should be optimized to make it faster then the general approach.  I might try writing some test latter tonight to see.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, my mistake I missed that it is a member; was imagining free `remove_if` coupled with `erase`. So, really, this isn't the erase-remove idiom at all.

Comment: @NathanOliver I could have done that but we can't use methods that haven't been used at class... Thanks tho, I will check it!

Comment: Yeah, I goofed originally with my comment and called both.  They've combined both into the member function so you just have a single function call to make.

Comment: @Nathan I expect `list::remove_if` wraps a loop like that shown in my answer; I see no reason for it to swap element values around then destroy the last _n_ elements, when it can simply walk the list unlinking (and destroying) nodes after performing comparisons. That was the crux of my performance concern! Indeed, the ability to just walk the list and quickly splice nodes out of it is the whole point of a linked list.

Comment: Aha.  I get that.

Comment: @PaueteGalopa I can imagine!

Comment: what is the use of `itend`, if you had used that it would be a big segmentation fault probably

Comment: @rioV8 No use at all, and you're right; I just didn't take it out of the original code, where it was also unused ;) I've added a section about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The used approach  in the function

```
void esborra_tots(list<Estudiant>& t, int x) {
    list<Estudiant>::iterator it;
    list<Estudiant>::iterator itend = t.end();

    for (it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); it++) {
        if ((*it).consultar_DNI() == x) {

            t.erase(it);
            if (t.empty()) return;
            else it = t.begin();
        }
    }
}
```

is invalid. The iterator becomes invalid after calling the method erase.

You could write the function like

```
void esborra_tots(list<Estudiant>& t, int x) {
    for ( auto it = t.begin(); it != t.end(); ) {
        if ((*it).consultar_DNI() == x) {

            it = t.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            ++it;
        } 
    }
}
```

But this is too complicated. The function will look much simpler if to use the method remove_if.

For example

```
void esborra_tots(list<Estudiant>& t, int x) {
    t.remove_if( [&x]( const auto &item ) { return item.consultar_DNI() == x; } );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> list = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( const auto &item : list ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    list.remove_if( []( const auto &item ){ return item % 2 == 0; } );

    for ( const auto &item : list ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I said I'm not looking for other approaches, college rules.

Comment: @PaueteGalopa I am very doubt that there are such rules. You could demonstrate your knowledge of the list.

Comment: If I use methods that haven't been teached in class the problem/exercise mark will be 0. It's just how it works and I don't like it either!

Just think that they are tying to teach us how to solve problems with the minimum resources. I'll have plenty of time to use all the STL functionality in the future!

I've used your answer to familiarize my self with *remove_if* it's been useful and well explained, thanks Vlad!

Comment: @PaueteGalopa learning stuff that is improper C++ just to get marks is even worse. You should point out the teacher that he is making a big mistake of not telling you about invalid iterators. If you program this on an interview you definitely are not asked for a next meeting.

Comment: @rioV8 I'm at college, first year of a 4 to 5 year course in . Before answering things like that think that there is a full Syllabus you are not aware of.

https://www.fib.upc.edu/en/studies/bachelors-degrees/bachelor-degree-informatics-engineering/curriculum/syllabus