# C++: Erasing an iterator from a map and then incrementing to the next iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, stdmap, allegro

This method causes an abort error: `"map/set iterator not incrementable."`
Due to that after the `if` fails and a vaild iterator that should be erased is determined, (and is), continuing to the next iterator in the map via `++_iter` fails because `_iter` is no longer a valid object/pointer.

What is the correct procedure for iterating through a map AND having the ability to remove individual items throughout?

```
typedef std::map<std::string, BITMAP*> MapStrBmp;
typedef MapStrBmp::iterator MapStrBmpIter;
\\...
void BitmapCache::CleanCache() {
    //Clean the cache of any NULL bitmaps that were deleted by caller.
    for(MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.begin(); _iter != _cache.end(); ++_iter) {
        if(_iter->second != NULL) {
            if((_iter->second->w < 0 && _iter->second->h < 0) == false) continue;
        }
        _cache.erase(_iter);
    }
}
```

Comment: @jrok: not applicable for `std::map` since its `value_type` is non copyable.

Comment: @ybungalobill I go heal my hole in the foot now...

Comment: and more fundamentally because the elements of a map do not form a sequence.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/800955/237483, http://stackoverflow.com/q/180516/237483, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8234779/237483, http://stackoverflow.com/q/1038708/237483,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to be a bit more careful:

```
void BitmapCache::CleanCache() {
    //Clean the cache of any NULL bitmaps that were deleted by caller.
    for(MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.begin(); _iter != _cache.end(); ) {
        if(_iter->second != NULL) {
            if((_iter->second->w < 0 && _iter->second->h < 0) == false)
            {
                ++_iter;
                continue;
            }
        }

        _cache.erase(_iter++);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining with words the changes you made, please, so we don't have to play "spot the differences"?

Comment: Why is incrementing the iterator inline in the erase command differnt to it be incremented on the next for loop? Just curious…

Comment: @v01pe: It's incremented *before* the call to `erase` invalidates it.

Comment: @v01pe: it's a postfix increment, so it increments the iterator to point to the next element, then passes a copy of the old iterator (that is to the item to be deleted) to `_cache.erase`. `map::erase` invalidates only iterators to elements that it actually deletes, so the current value of `_iter` remains valid and it points to the next element.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I know that it's a postfix increment, but I didn't know, that a copy of the old value (iterator in that case) is evaluated. I thought the value it self is passed, and will be incremented at the end (not upfront) of the expression. Good to know!

Answer (score 2):

`map::erase(iterator)` gives you an iterator pointing to the next element in the map (if any) after erasing. Therefore, you can do:

```
for(MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.begin(); _iter != _cache.end(); ) {
    if(_iter->second != NULL) {
        if((_iter->second->w < 0 && _iter->second->h < 0) == false) {
           ++_iter;
           continue;
        }
    }
    _iter = _cache.erase(_iter);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's only since C++11. C++03 version returns `void`.

Comment: I think this is not even valid in C++11. The function prototype for erase in C++11 looks like this `iterator erase( const_iterator pos )`.

Answer (score 1):

The standard erase loop for an associative container:

```
for (auto it = m.cbegin(); it != m.cend() /* not hoisted */; /* no increment */)
{
    if (delete_condition)
    {
        m.erase(it++);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to safely erase iterators during an iteration is to use the result of `container::erase`:

```
void BitmapCache::CleanCache() {
    //Clean the cache of any NULL bitmaps that were deleted by caller.
    MapStrBmpIter _iter = _cache.begin();
    while (_iter != _cache.end()) {
        bool erase_entry= true;
        if(_iter->second != NULL) {
            if((_iter->second->w < 0 && _iter->second->h < 0) == false) 
                erase_entry= false;
        }

        if (erase_entry)
            _iter= _cache.erase(_iter);
        else
            ++_iter;
    }
}
```