# Delete all entries in STL Map which matches value

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I'm trying to delete all entries in a map where value == 50 for any key.

This code is working fine for me.

```
 while (itr != mymap.end())
 {
    if ((*itr).second == 50)
        mymap.erase(itr++);
     else
        itr++;

 }
```

But this code is giving run time error.

```
while (itr != mymap.end())
{
    if ((*itr).second == 50)
    {    
        mymap.erase(itr);
        itr++
    }
    else
        itr++;

}
```

My doubt is aren't both logic is same? why run time error in second case?

Comment: In the second case you're incrementing an invalid iterator (because you just deleted the item it points to). Consider using [erase/remove idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038708/erase-remove-contents-from-the-map-or-any-other-stl-container-while-iterating)

Comment: what is happening in the first case?? same, deleting and incrementing? right?

Comment: No, the increment happens first, but it++ returns the original value (unlike ++it) so you delete the right item but the iterator already points to the next one.

Comment: @Borgleader, note that `remove_if` is not available for map containers since it is not possible to move elements to the end of the container in the case of map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the logic is not the same. 
In the first case the iterator is postincremented before erasing the element when it is a valid iterator.
In the second case the iterator is postincremented after erasing the element when it is an invalid iterator.

The common approach to this operation is the following

```
while ( itr != mymap.end() )
{
    if ( (*itr).second == 50 )
        itr = mymap.erase( itr );
     else
        itr++;
}
```

According to the C++ Standard (23.2.4 Associative containers)

> 9 The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of
>   iterators and references to the container, and **the erase members
>   shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased
>   elements**.